# Attribution required, but it was required after a while? is it retro active?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I wonder how this works, since the 'Attribution' required was a clause added at some point AFTER the initial data dumps, does this mean all content before that date can be used w/o attribution?

(note: I am not using the data at all, just curiuos).

Comment: *Was* it added afterwards?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that clause was *always* there. It just wasn't clarified until June of '09.

Comment: i think it was added.

Comment: Attribution required was set before the site even started. Jeff had a blog post about it.

Answer (score 10):

The CC license pre-dates the data dump.

[Now Licensed Under Creative Commons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/) - Posted by Jeff Atwood on May 5th, 2008

[Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) - Posted by Jeff Atwood on June 4th, 2009